# spawn ffmpeg in nodejs and pipe to express's response

Tags: node.js, express, ffmpeg

i am spawning ffmpeg and pipe it's output (the video stream i want) to express's response object like this:

```
app.get('/stream', (req, res) => {
    let _url = req.query.url;

    if(_url){   

        res.writeHead(200, {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Connection': 'Keep-Alive',
            'Content-Type': 'video/mp4'
        });

        // transcode rtsp input from ip-cam to mp4 file format (video: h.264 | audio: aac)
        let ffmpeg = child_process.spawn("ffmpeg",[
            "-probesize","2147483647",
            "-analyzeduration","2147483647",
            "-i", _url,
            "-vcodec","copy",
            "-f", "mp4",            
            "-movflags","frag_keyframe+empty_moov+faststart",
            "-frag_duration","3600",
            "pipe:1"              
        ]);         


        // redirect transcoded ip-cam stream to http response
        ffmpeg.stdout.pipe(res);

        // error logging
        ffmpeg.stderr.setEncoding('utf8');      
        ffmpeg.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
            console.log(data);
        });
    }
    else{
        res.end();
    }
```

so far it's working like a charm.
however somewhere in there seems to be a cap. i can get only 3 streams running at the same time. when a 4th spawn occurs the 4th thread will block one of the cpu cores:

[image: htop of my raspberry pi 3]

and naturally the 4th stream does not reach the browser.. 
has somebody any idea of what am i missing?

EDIT: it's not tied to the fact that i am running the nodejs project on the raspberry pi. it also behaves the same way on my windows 10 machine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jesus. Alright here is the problem:

My IP-camera can only deliver 3-4 streams at the same time anyway...